# {}\edef \Hy@tempb {cite.\XR@prefix error when citing same bibtex entry in \externaldocument

Tags: bibtex, hyperref, xr

I have the following `.tex` file in a folder

```
main.tex
---
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{}
\author{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\cite{entry}

\bibliography{bib}{}
\bibliographystyle{plain}


\end{document}
```

In the same folder, I have another file that uses the main one as an `\externaldocument`, *also* citing the same entry `entry` from the same `bib` file:

```
secondary.tex
---
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{xr}
\externaldocument{main}

\title{}
\author{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\cite{entry}

\bibliography{bib}{}
\bibliographystyle{plain}


\end{document}
```

The problem is that when I compile `secondary.tex` I get the following error, pointing to the citation:

```
--- TeX said ---
<argument> ... {}\edef \Hy@tempb {cite.\XR@prefix
                                                  entry\@extra@b@citeb }\ifx...l.15 \cite{entry}
```

Other symptoms:

- no error if I remove `hyperref`
- no error if I turn off `\externaldocument`
- no error if `entry` is only cited in one of the documents
- even with the error, if I persist and run `bibtex` and then `pdflatex` a couple more times the document actually compiles fine, bibliography and everything. So the error just gets ploughed over.

Answer (score 2):

I get the error only when the aux-file doesn't contain the bibentry command (so the compilation order is crucial).

You can avoid the error by using the xr-hyper package:

```
\usepackage{xr-hyper}

\usepackage{hyperref}
```

But this doesn't prevent that you get multiply defined labels, so using a prefix for the external document should be done too.

Comment: Hmm.. I think I'll settle for just adding a plain prefix, since that seems to resolve the matter. But I'm curious now: what would be the compilation order that obviates the error *without* the prefix? I thought that for the references in `main` to get recognized in `secondary` you need to compile `main` first and then `secondary`, which is what I was doing to begin with..